# Is "automatically eraseing" or "being erased automatically" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, passive-voice

Please tell me which sentence is correct:

**My file is automatically eraseing.**

or

**My file is being erased automatically.**

Comment: Not all dictionaries give as broad a definition for the intransitive usage of _erase_ as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erase) seems to: **erase** intransitive verb:  to yield to erasure (but they all give the correct spelling of _erasing_). But is 'yield to' intended to refer to a fairly rapid instance (the ice quickly melted) as well as being a generic statement (ice melts at 273K)(?)   I'd stick with the second variant.

Comment: Your subject doesn't match the question. You use "erasing" instead of "eraseing".

Comment: @Edwin: OED defines the intransitive as a "quasi-passive" usage, for which their only citation is 1837: *Things, which lie very black in our Earth's Annals, yet which will not **erase** therefrom.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

I'd choose the latter phrasing, "my file is being erased automatically", because the first construction is ambiguous and could also mean either of the following:

- my file is self-erasing
- my file has an automatic erasure feature (erasing taken as a gerund)

Comment: Or a third: the file is automatically erasing *something else* - grammatically, it may be read as doing the erasing, not being erased.

Comment: Reading (1)'s availability is dubious, as FF says.

Comment: Please tell me how can say that 'my file is erased automatically'in simple present tense